# Create Form Template from existing ones

Tags: acumatica

Is there any way that I can create a template within forms to utilize for every user in the company?
For instance; let's say I have the Sales Order Screen (SO301000) and the Document Detail grid configured in certain way, that display different amount of columns than the default (either more or less columns). 
For each user I want to use this template (and all the ones created) that I will apply when I add the new user.
I'l appreciate any guidance and help.

Comment: I think I initially misunderstood your question. What you're looking for is Default Table Layout: https://help.acumatica.com/(W(1))/Main?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=30f3229f-20f1-4055-9c03-e0fe3b37080d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:
I provided answer for Form element ASP template below. Although reading your question again I think what you're trying to do would be more along the lines of automating grid column configuration. We call this feature Default Table Layout.

There's a feature request for it here:
https://feedback.acumatica.com/ideas/ACU-I-415

The feature has been shipped in version 2017R2 and is documented here:
https://help.acumatica.com/(W(1))/Main?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=30f3229f-20f1-4055-9c03-e0fe3b37080d

Image copy of documentation page:
[image]

---

For ASP Form templates

There are two ways to work with customizations in Acumatica:

1. As a Customization Project, everything is done directly in Acumatica
   instance through the web browser using the Customization Project Editor.
2. As an extension library (DLL file) compiled in Visual Studio which is then included in the FILES section of a Customization Project.

For method 1, I believe creating custom templates would be a bit of a hack and would not be officially supported, if someone knows otherwise please chime in.

For method 2, we ship the Visual Studio templates with the Acumatica Configuration Wizard (Acumatica ERP Installer).

Those templates are in the following folder:

`My Documents\Visual Studio 20XX\Templates\ItemTemplates\Visual C`#

[image]

The templates will be available for ASP.NET solution only. You can open Acumatica Instance Website as a solution if the website is already deployed:
[image]

When you open Add New Item dialog:
[image]

The Acumatica Templates will be available:
[image]

Those are standard Visual Studio templates so you can copy and re-use them to create your own. Microsoft documentation for creating user template applies and you can follow their guidelines. Note that working with Visual Studio and creating your own template is somewhat less user friendly than using Acumatica Customization Project Editor.

Acumatica T100 covers using Visual Studio to create customizations and would be a good starting point to learn the techniques involved:

https://openuni.acumatica.com/courses/development/t100-introduction-to-acumatica-framework/